# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionToRoute' of null

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi I am using ember for my client side application .here is my code which is in emberView

When I want to use transitionToRoute inside the kill action, it is showing the above error.

and my routes are like this

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route('groups');
  this.resource('group', { path: 'group/:uuid' }, function() {
    this.route('people');
    this.route('vehicles');
    this.route('reports');
    this.route('geofences');
  });
 });
```

currently I am at the route of child View (group/:uuid/people) and once if i call the above Tile View of kill action it has redirect to parentRoute of (groups)

```
App.TileView = Ember.View.extend({
actions:{

     kill: function() {
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();
        var t = this,resolveEntity = false;
        this.set('waitingOnDelete', true);

        //this.get('entity').kill().done(this.remove.bind(this));

        var pid = this.get('entity').id;
        this.get('entity').kill().then(function() {
            t.remove();
            if ((t.get('entityType') === 'association') && (DS.session.user_uuid === pid)) {
                resolveEntity = true;
                dfd.resolve(resolveEntity);
                if(resolveEntity){
                  t.get('controller').transitionToRoute('groups');
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
});
```